# Tesseract OCR Android in Windows

Tags: android, windows, android-ndk, ocr, tesseract

I've read all of questions forums and blogs about it but i still have a problem. Firstly, i ticked tess-two as a library also my project's using tess-two as a library. I downloaded Android-NDK and from my project's properties i clicked Builders and then new -> Program then i choose ndk's ndk-build file. By the way my project is Gautam Gupta's project. He'd given project. Link: https://github.com/GautamGupta/Simple-Android-OCR. When i run that project in my phone, application starts and captures photo but when i press save then application gives error below. http://t1307.hizliresim.com/1c/l/qg0rl.png

Comment: Do you have in the library project the following folder-structure? `libs -> armeabi/armeabi-v7a/mips/x86`? And in each folder `liblept.so` and `libtess.so`?

Comment: That's my library project. https://github.com/rmtheis/tess-two/tree/master/tess-two and it's not lib folder.

Comment: You'll have to build them yourself ... let me check how I did it and will add an answer.

Comment: I didn't build it, okay i am waiting.

Comment: According to eyes-two's readme i have to do git clone git://github.com/rmtheis/tess-two tess cd tess cd tess-two ndk-build android update project --path . ant release but when i write it to cmd it gives error

Comment: what error? do you have ndk installed? ... holding on with the answer

Comment: i've unzipped ndk to my desktop. I think i didn't connect relationship between eclipse and ndk. Here is cmd's error http://j1307.hizliresim.com/1c/l/qg1ws.png

Comment: Can we chat about this?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33693/discussion-between-gunar-and-burak)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you need to download only [TessTwo](https://github.com/rmtheis/tess-two), make sure you have properly setup the environments variables (ANT_HOME, ANDROID_HOME and ANDROID_NDK) so these point to where you have *Ant* and *Android SDKs*.

Then it's a matter of building the project by following TessTwo guidance. That you set up the library-project that can be imported.

Don't forget that the line commands must be performed in CygWin. Once the library project is built you should have correct *.so* files in *libs/**. In order to actually use these, you could start with [this link](http://gaut.am/making-an-ocr-android-app-using-tesseract/).

---

@Burak:
I have solved my problem. For Windows;
Write the codes below to Cygwin

```
a.cd <project-path'i>/tess-two
b.export TESSERACT_PATH=${PWD}/external/tesseract-3.01
c.export  LEPTONICA_PATH=${PWD}/external/leptonica-1.68
d.export LIBJPEG_PATH=${PWD}/external/libjpeg
e./cygdrive/<ndk-directory>/ndk-build
```

Write the codes below to CMD

```
f.android update project --target 1 --path .
g. ant release
```

Don't forget the "." at step f.

Comment: f.android update project --target 1 --path .
 android is not a recognized as an internal ar external command operable program or batch file
pls tell me what is "project" and "target 1"....

Comment: did you write that code snippet to cmd, didn't you? If so can you upload the screenshot?

Comment: @Ani: you need to make sure you have added Android utilities in system `Path`