# Using OCR on smartphone

Tags: android, ios, iphone, ocr

I need to get text from an image on android and iphone apps.

I have seen tesseract ocr, but I'm not sure if I can make it work on both Android and IOS.

Then I looked for Google drive API. It seems easier to do, just upload the image and it should do the job.

But I feel lost when reading the drive API, I must use a google account with drive enabled? Is there any other way to only perform the OCR and skip uploading the file to an account?

Anyone knows a good way to achieve this?

EDIT:

All of u are recommending tesseract, so i downloaded tess-two, but its really not working, it says:

```
01-16 12:00:25.339: I/Tesseract(native)(29038): Initialized Tesseract API with language=spa
```

and like 30 seconds later it shows this as result string:

```
{ga
 .,
r¿
 y“: A
  r M í
:3 
'  ‘Ev’.-:.. -: A 7
 » w- ?" _
 Á.» ¿"A ¿rw-V r
 mjÏfn 'n’n . Y
' "\'ZA".‘.¡ A‘ :‘ïvAv- « ‘
:"Éf‘Ï'" -Ï«l :‘,.v:...»- .
 ' RFI' .. ’ g)" 3;:- 1-;4',
= * ¿,arifgggk mw; .1.  ,
'  "53» "J
't‘ ‘ ¿Las ;.‘».L',-‘»
 ' '  'N‘“ "“=: - '. V  .  ‘9!
5.? ' “F a .“ 
Y , <_  7- . 7.-, .
;«  z "1:;2wr . A - . ' -»‘ 5“:
“4-”, ¿rn 73:33: w v'.‘ ¿a ‘ A ,z, v VA
...,,« ' 'Q ' ‘ 4 214€. 5 . AV ¿JL y .13:
1  » . 21mm; » ¿ati-“ﬂ ¿ab-1377*“ w”
. x ‘ ‘ ú  F v'v: 
1 . ' . ; (“ya  í .
```

of course thats not correct, im using this photo:

[image: photo]

its spanish, but should it work with english trained data?

What can be wrong?

Comment: At least for Android, I used [this approach](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17724517/1051783) and it wasn't that complicated. Also no registrations/accounts needed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Tess-two OCR not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21161352/tess-two-ocr-not-working)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tesseract OCR is Free library. Offline. Good accuracy for printed text for many fonts. Some times fails to read numbers and handwritten text in caps, but mostly can read it. Accuracy for handwritten text is less.
Work fine with iOS.