# Obtaining a really really bad recognition using tesstwo

Tags: android, ocr

I'm trying to to implement OCR using [these](http://androidadvance.com/blog/tutorial-getting-started-with-tessaract-ocr-in-android-android-studio/) steps.

But the recognition of the words was really bad!
I tried to type "Apple" in a word and to capture it using the application
the output was "ADPIB" 
and also I tried to capture " The quick brown fox jumped over the 5 lazy dogs"
and the output was --

> THB QUECK DFGVVM F0X
>                                                                              IUFHPBCI 0VBF IHB 5
>                                                                                     UBZV 00085

I tried the solution mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21161352/tess-two-ocr-not-working), but nothing changed.